# bs4 scraping selection inside object

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib

This is my first attempt in scraping some subtitles from the web with beautifulsoup. That's still far from my objective but for the time being, I just want to achieve this (I'm learning slowly :D)

I'm only interested in one language inside this "tr" object.

[image]

The code below gets all subtitles objects because I don't know how to filter my selection inside the "tr" objects:

```
import urllib.request as urlRequest
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urlpage = 'https://www.tusubtitulo.com/season/4674/1'
# pretend to be a chrome 47 browser on a windows 10 machine
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)"
req = urlRequest.Request(urlpage, headers=headers)
# open the url
url = urlRequest.urlopen(req)
# get the source code
source_code = url.read()

# parse the html using beautiful soup and store in variable 'soup'
soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code, 'html.parser')

results = []
for lang in soup.findAll("td", class_="language"):
    if "Español (España)" in str(lang):
        for element in soup.findAll("a", class_="bt_descarga"):
            results.append(element)
results
```

Comment: Even if you filter out the Spanish subtitles, you won't get the `href`'s as there's a `JS` event listener there. In other words, there are no links to the files in the HTML source.

Comment: That's right. But that will be a problem for the "future", that's why I say it's still far from being finished :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your language filter isn't working because you're trying to find bt_descarga from all HTML.

bs4 has an attribute that is called a [parent](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#parent). You can access an element’s parent with the parent attribute.
lang is also the bs4 object which you can call the bs4 attributes.

As a result, you should reach the filtered lang class's parent tr tag and find bt_descarga. like,

```
for lang in soup.findAll("td", class_="language"):
  if "Español (España)" in str(lang):
    for element in lang.parent.findAll("a", class_="bt_descarga"):
        results.append(element)
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is the Spanish only subtitles (*since there's no hrefs and that's a thing for the future*) you can grab all `descarga` elements and grab the first one and then every 3rd one onwards.

You should end up with 10 titles.

Here's how:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:95.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/95.0",
}
page = requests.get("https://www.tusubtitulo.com/season/4674/1", headers=headers).text
spanish_only = [
    a["title"] for a in BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml").select(".bt_descarga")[1::3]
]
print("\n".join(spanish_only))
```

Output:

```
Invasion (2021) 1x01 - Last Day
Invasion (2021) 1x02 - Crash
Invasion (2021) 1x03 - Orion
Invasion (2021) 1x04 - The King is Dead
Invasion (2021) 1x05 - Going Home
Invasion (2021) 1x06 - Home Invasion
Invasion (2021) 1x07 - Hope
Invasion (2021) 1x08 - Contact
Invasion (2021) 1x09 - Full of Stars
Invasion (2021) 1x10 - First Day
```